# using __slots__ is faster than a dict, but initiation is slower, any workaround?

Tags: python, performance, class, dictionary, slots

So I am trying to have a faster creation + attribute access than a `dict()`

so assuming a very simple class / dict you can see that `__slots__` is faster/equivalent for attribute access:
import timeit

```
class A:
    __slots__ = ('a',)

    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a

a = A(10)
v = {'B': 10}

%timeit A.a
%timeit v['B']
10000000 loops, best of 3: 28.3 ns per loop
10000000 loops, best of 3: 29 ns per loop
```

but if you test the speed including initiation of the class / dict the results are very different :

```
%timeit A(10).a
%timeit {'B': 10}['B']
1000000 loops, best of 3: 216 ns per loop
10000000 loops, best of 3: 58.8 ns per loop
```

is there any way to speed up the initiation phase of the class? Why is `dict()` initiation so much faster?

thanks!

Comment: Interesting, seems like the attribute access is on par. I wonder if a `cython` extension type is created much faster?

Comment: I wouldn't call 0.7 ns faster.

Comment: @JamesSchinner that's my guess. dict() is implemented in C but the class has to go through the Python Object shenigans